# Nested UNWIND not returning from higher UNWIND in Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following query

```
UNWIND $towns as town
MERGE (a:area:Town {Name: town.name, uuid: town.uuid}) with a, town
MATCH (p:parish{Name: town.parish}) with a, p, town
MERGE (a)-[:in]-(p) with a, town
UNWIND town.categories as category
MATCH (c:LocationCategory {uuid: category}) 
MERGE (a)-[:category]-(c) 
RETURN a
```

`town.categories` can be null so I'm guessing the second `UNWIND` doesn't return a row for the null values of the categories, fine. But I'don't care about returning any row from the second unwind because it might not return any. But I want to return all the original `a` nodes. How do I break the second unwind so I can return `a` regularly as if it wasn't there?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `UNWIND` for a `FOREACH` by using a `MERGE` instead of a `MATCH` in the second batch.

That would then solve the issue for the second unwind breaking your results in case of nulls

```
UNWIND $towns as town
MERGE (a:area:Town {Name: town.name, uuid: town.uuid}) with a, town
MATCH (p:parish{Name: town.parish}) with a, p, town
MERGE (a)-[:in]-(p) with a, town
FOREACH (category IN town.categories |
  MERGE (c:LocationCategory {uuid: category}) 
  MERGE (a)-[:category]-(c)
)
RETURN a
```